# Form to update row in database where form is generated from php while loop

Tags: php, html

I have an interesting challenge that I haven't been able to get my head around, I have a html table that is generated from php while loop and a mysql database, each generated row of this table has a button that allows someone to modify a row in a database, but whenever the button is pressed the action is performed across the whole generated table thanks to the while loop, and I don't know how to only get that row to perform an action.

Here is the code that I have so far in this section.

```
while ($submissionrow = mysqli_fetch_array($currentsubmissions)) {
                if ($submissionrow[approved] === '1') {
                  $approvedtick = 'Approved';
                }else {
                  $approvedtick = '';
                }
                if ($submissionrow[rejected] === '1') {
                  $rejectedsymbol = 'Rejected';
                }else {
                  $rejectedsymbol = '';
                }
                if ($approvedtick == $blanksymbol && $rejectedsymbol == $blanksymbol) {
                  $inreviewmessage = 'In Review';
                }else {
                  $inreviewmessage = '';
                }
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $submissionrow[submission_ID] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $submissionrow[Username] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $currentyear . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $submissionrow[CSEvent] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . "";?>
                <form method='post' action='<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>'>
                  <?php
                echo "<button type='submit' name='$submissionrow[submission_ID]' id='accept_cs'>Approve</button>";
                echo "<button type='submit' name='$submissionrow[submission_ID]' id='reject_cs'>Reject</button>";
                ?>
                </form>
<?php echo "


                " . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $approvedtick . $rejectedsymbol . $inreviewmessage .  "</td>";
                if(isset($_POST['accept_cs'])) {
                  $accept_cs_sql = 'UPDATE CommunityService SET approved =1 WHERE submission_ID =' . $submissionrow[submission_ID];
                  printf($accept_cs_sql);
                  $retval = $dbcon->query("$accept_cs_sql");
                  echo "Updated Accepted Status successfully\n";
                }
              if(isset($_POST['reject_cs'])) {
                $reject_cs_sql = 'UPDATE CommunityService SET rejected =1 WHERE submission_ID =' . $submissionrow[submission_ID];
                printf($reject_cs_sql);
                $retval = $dbcon->query("$reject_cs_sql");
                echo "Updated Rejected Status successfully\n";
                }
              }
```

I can make the code submit the performed action, but it enacts this action on the ID of every row in the table, not just the row with that button that was pressed.

Thank you in advance
-jx

Comment: First of all the code after `if(isset($_POST['accept_cs'])) {` this row shouldn't be in the loop.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm Hi, Thanks for getting back to me, I have moved the two "isset" blocks outside of the while loop but still am not able to get the desired result? Is it to do with the way that I handle the unique rows?